# How can I convert from SQLite3 format to dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, dictionary

How can i convert my SQLITE3 TABLE to a python dictionary where the name and value of the column of the table is converted to key and value of dictionary.

Comment: Use a [row factory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.row_factory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a package to solve this issue if anyone got into this problem..

[aiosqlitedict](https://github.com/sabrysm/aiosqlitedict)

**Here is what it can do**

> 1. Easy conversion between sqlite table and Python dictionary and vice-versa.
> 2. Get values of a certain column in a Python list.
> 3. Order your list ascending or descending.
> 4. Insert any number of columns to your dict.

### Getting Started

We start by connecting our database along with
the reference column

```py
from aiosqlitedict.database import Connect

countriesDB = Connect("database.db", "user_id")
```

### Make a dictionary

The dictionary should be inside an async function.

```py
async def some_func():
    countries_data = await countriesDB.to_dict("my_table_name", 123, "col1_name", "col2_name", ...)
```

You can insert any number of columns, or you can get all by specifying
the column name as '*'

```py
    countries_data = await countriesDB.to_dict("my_table_name", 123, "*")
```

so you now have made some changes to your dictionary and want to
export it to sql format again?

### Convert dict to sqlite table

```py
async def some_func():
    ...
    await countriesDB.to_sql("my_table_name", 123, countries_data)
```

But what if you want a list of values for a specific column?

### Select method

you can have a list of all values of a certain column.

```py
country_names = await countriesDB.select("my_table_name", "col1_name")
```

to limit your selection use `limit` parameter.

```py
country_names = await countriesDB.select("my_table_name", "col1_name", limit=10)
```

you can also arrange your `list` by using `ascending` parameter
and/or `order_by` parameter and specifying a certain column to order your list accordingly.

```py
country_names = await countriesDB.select("my_table_name", "col1_name", order_by="col2_name", ascending=False)
```